# Splitting Field of $x^6-3x^4+3x^2-3$ \ Normal Extension \ Subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field, normal-extension

i'm trying to solve the problem above. Let's name L the splitting field.
Using $x^2=t$, i have found 6 roots $$\alpha=\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{2}} \\ \beta=\sqrt{1+\varepsilon\sqrt[3]{2}} \\ \gamma=\sqrt{1+\varepsilon^2\sqrt[3]{2}} \\ -\alpha, -\beta, -\gamma,$$ where $\varepsilon$ is a 3rd root of unity. So, L should be $\mathbb{Q} (\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$. 
I can't understand if i can simplify the writing of L; i found that $\beta,\gamma\notin\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, because $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, but i can't go further than this. Actually, i had to study subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, and the only tool i have is Galois theory, so i tried this way, but maybe there is a better one, let me know!

Comment: Is there a reason you want a simpler version? Did you just want a simpler version, or did you want to answer whether  this is a normal field extension, as mentioned in the title?

Comment: i guess both things could be useful, even if the real question is wheteher $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) /\mathbb{Q}$ is normal @ThomasAndrews

Comment: You can see that $\mathbb{Q} (\alpha) $ is not a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q} $ as it does not  contain all the roots of the given polynomial. However there is one subfield $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2})$ over which it is normal. The proper way to find all the subfields is to find the splitting field and the Galois group and use Galois correspondence between subgroups and subfields.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh i will try, thanks!